# Delete author message after executing roll command

Tags: python, asynchronous, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm struggling to delete author message e.g. roll and still have it execute my command.

(Discord.py Async 0.16 'i think')

````
@client.command(name = 'roll',
                 description = 'Rolls a 6 sided dice.',
                 brief = 'Rolls a dice!',
                 pass_context = True)
async def dice(context):
    possible_responses = [
        ':game_die: 1',
        ':game_die: 2',
        ':game_die: 3',
        ':game_die: 4',
        ':game_die: 5',
        ':game_die: 6'
    ]
    await client.say(context.message.author.mention + ' , Rolls a ' + random.choice(possible_responses))```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add: `await client.delete_message(context.message)`

Your code should look like:

```
@client.command(name = 'roll',
                 description = 'Rolls a 6 sided dice.',
                 brief = 'Rolls a dice!',
                 pass_context = True)
async def dice(context):
    possible_responses = [
        ':game_die: 1',
        ':game_die: 2',
        ':game_die: 3',
        ':game_die: 4',
        ':game_die: 5',
        ':game_die: 6'
    ]
    await client.say(context.message.author.mention + ' , Rolls a ' + random.choice(possible_responses))
    await client.delete_message(context.message)
```

This will delete the message after the command has run, make sure the bot has the correct permissions to delete messages. You can find more information on the discord.py 0.16 docs

Comment: Wonderful worked a treat, i had it in the wrong place and it was deleting it before executing. +1